# $\sigma$-algebra generated by a function of a random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables

I having difficulty specifying the exact sets in $\sigma(W)$ for the following problem.

Suppose $X$ is uniformly distributed on $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$. Define $W:=\lfloor X/2\rfloor$. The answer given in the example is to define $A_{0}=\{W=0\}=\{1\}$, $A_{1}=\{W=1\}=\{2,3\}$ and $A_{2}=\{W=2\}=\{4,5\}$ and then since $\{A_{0},A_{1},A_{2}\}$ "is a partition of $\Omega$" we have $\sigma(W)=\{\bigcup\limits_{i\in I} A_{i} : I\subset\{0,1,2\}\}$. What I don't understand is that $\Omega$ has not been specified, $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ is just the sample space of X. Should, for example, the set $A_{1}$ be defined as $A_{1}=\{W=1\}=\{X=2\}\cup\{X=3\}$? If so, what are the repercussions for $\sigma$(W) if we want to write out each of its sets?

EDIT: Changed notation according to spalein's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your writing to determine the sets $A_i$ is not quite right.

Let me first make the notation clear.

You say $\Omega$ is not specified. The reason for this is: It can be any probability space and there is no need for knowing it, because for this probability model all information is already  in the phrase "$X$ uniformly distributed on $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$".

Thus let $(\Omega , \mathcal F , \Bbb P )$ the probability space on which $X$ is defined. This means $X$ is a function $\Omega \to \{1, \ldots , 5\}$.

For any random variable $Z : \Omega \to \Bbb R$ the notation $\{Z = x\}$ for $x\in \Bbb R$ means

$$\{Z=x\} := \{\omega \in \Omega : Z(\omega ) = x \}$$

Hence $\{W = 0\}$ is not $\{1\}$, but
$$\{W=0\} = \{\omega \in \Omega : W (\omega ) = 0 \} \\= \{\omega \in \Omega : \lfloor X (\omega ) /2 \rfloor = 0 \} = \{\omega \in \Omega : X (\omega ) = 1 \} = \{X= 1\}$$
In the same manner $\{W= 1\} = \{X = 2\} \cup \{X=3\} = \{X \in \{2,3\} \}$ and $\{W=2\} = \{X=4\}\cup\{X=5\} = \{X \in \{4,5\} \}$.

Together this yields
$$\bigcup_{i=1}^2 A_i = \bigcup_{k=1}^5 \{X=k\}= \{X \in \{1,\ldots , 5\}\} = \Omega$$
thus $A_1 , A_2 , A_3$ is a partition of $\Omega$ regardless of knowing $\Omega$ exactly.

If you want to write out the set $\sigma (W)$ you have to work out the conditions for a [$\sigma$-algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A3-algebra), since the $A_i$ are disjoint you just have to add the paarwise unions:

$$\sigma (W) = \{ \emptyset , \Omega , A_0 , A_1 , A_2 , \{X \in \{1,2,3\} \}, \{X \in \{1,4,5\} ,\{X \in \{2,3,4,5\} \} \}\}$$